# Add Eventhandler to Object of type Word.Application

Tags: ms-word, lotus-notes, lotusscript

With the following code I open a a new word document. To save the word document programmatically I want to add an event listener to the object, which occurs when word will be closed. Is this possible?

```
    Set objWord = createobject("Word.Application")
    objWord.visible = True
    Set objDoc = objWord.documents.add()
    Call objDoc.content.select()
    Set selection = objWord.selection()
    Call selection.collapse()

    objDoc.Close
    Set objDoc = Nothing
    objWord.Quit
    Set objWord = Nothing
```

EDIT:

I try to explain better what I want to do. My Lotusscript Agent should open a word document for the user. The user types in some text and then closes the word document. Instead of showing the save dialog of word I want to save the document programmatically to embedd the file as attachment to an notes document. Until now I have not found a solution to get an handle of the event when word is closing.

Comment: Please explain a little more, because I'm not sure if I understand. I added the ms-word tag in addtion to the lotus-notes and lotusscript tags that you specified because I think you need some experts on Word scripting to look at this. Are you trying to use LotusScript within Lotus Notes (or Domino) to create a new document, and to programmatically add some VBA code into that document as an event listener that will fire when MS Word is closed? I have a feeling that that's not going to be allowed by Word's scripting, but again I think that you need some Word experts looking this.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this link on one of the ldd wikis](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/HowTo_Create_a_Word_Document_from_LotusScript) probably has what you need. If you are a little clearer on what you need, you may get better answers though.

I think you are wanting to be notified when word closes so you can force a save or something correct? You can already force the save using similar lotusscript to how you are closing it, you don't need to wait until they close it themselves.